# strcpy doesn't work in C with pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

My code looks like that:

```
char *token;
token = strtok(myStrings, delimiter);
char newArray[MAXCHARS];

while (token != NULL) {
    printf("%s\n", token);
    strcpy(newArray, &token);
    token = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
}
```

I want to `add` the token to my char array but it doesn't work. 
It prints the right token (e.g. Martin) but I can't add it to my char array.

Comment: get rid of the `&` in front of `token` in your `strcpy`

Comment: `&token` is a `char**`. You should call `strcpy(newArray, token)`.

Comment: I want to add the values to the array, so it has to look like that: array = {Martin, Paul, Ashley}

Comment: Sorry but I haven't worked with C before

Comment: then you'll need something like `char newArray[MAXNAMES][MAXCHARS];` and you'll have to `strcpy(newArray[i], token);` where `i` is incremented each time through the loop

Comment: Use `strcat(newArray, token)` but clear `newArray` before loop: `newArray[0] = 0`. `strcpy` will overwrite last value.

Comment: `strcpy` requires two arguments, both of type `char*` (well, the second is of type `const char*`, but you can pass it a `char*`).  Your second argument is of type `char**`. Your compiler should have warned you about the mismatch. If it did, *pay attention to the warning*. If it didn't, find out how to enable reasonable warnings from your compiler. (If you're getting compile-time warnings, don't even think about running the program until you've resolved them. Usually means fixing the code so the warnings go away; on rare occasions it might mean understanding what the warnings are saying.)